# Why I have some junk bytes while receiving file with UDP Socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I writed a client/server program in C, where the client send the file to the server.
It works, but some junk bytes are added to the received file at the position of 1400 of the byte.
I tried with a text file and I setted to 0 the memory before any sent.
Why that junk bytes?

Here the code:

macro.h

```
#ifndef MACRO_H
#define MACRO_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>


#define SERV_PORT 49312
#define MAXLINE   1400

#define END_FLAG "================END"

#define abort_on_error(cond, msg) do {                                          \
    if (cond) {                                                                 \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s (errno=%d [%s])\n", msg, errno, strerror(errno));   \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                     \
    }                                                                           \
} while (0)

struct pkt {
    // struct sockaddr_in addr;
    // int sockfd;
    uint16_t seq_num;
    uint32_t status;
    uint8_t data[MAXLINE];
};

typedef struct pkt PACK;

#endif // MACRO_H
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "macro.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, n, count = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    // char buf[MAXLINE];
    char *target, *path;
    FILE *file;
    PACK packet;
    long filesize;

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    path = argv[2];
    target = argv[3];

    packet.seq_num = 0;
    packet.status = 0;
    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    memcpy(packet.data, target, strlen(target));

    abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1,
                    "sendto() filename error");

    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    abort_on_error(recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, NULL, NULL) == -1, "recvfrom() ok error");
    if (!strncmp((const char *) packet.data, "ok", 2)) {
        printf("Filename sent.\n");
    }

    file = fopen(path, "r");
    abort_on_error(file == NULL, "fopen() error");

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    printf("filesize: %ld\n", filesize);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    sprintf((char *) packet.data, "%ld", filesize);

    abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1,
                        "sendto() data error");

    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    while ((n = fread(packet.data, sizeof(char), MAXLINE, file))) {
        // packet.data[n] = '\0';
        // printf("n: %d\n", n);
        abort_on_error(n == -1, "fread() error");
        abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1,
                        "sendto() data error");
        count = count + n;
        memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    }
    printf("Tot Bytes sent: %d\n", count);

    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    memcpy(packet.data, END_FLAG, strlen(END_FLAG));
    abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1,
                    "sendto() end_flag error");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include "macro.h"

void run(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *cliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
    int n = 0, count = 0, status = 0;
    socklen_t len;
    // char buf[MAXLINE];
    FILE *file;
    PACK packet;

    len = clilen;
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len);
    abort_on_error(n == -1, "recvfrom() filename error");
    // buf[n] = 0;
    printf("Received from client: [%s]\n", packet.data);

    file = fopen((const char *) packet.data, "w+");
    abort_on_error(file == NULL, "fopen() error");

    packet.seq_num = 0;
    packet.status = 0;
    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    memcpy(packet.data, "ok", strlen("ok"));
    abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, len) == -1,
                    "sendto() ok error");

    memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
    abort_on_error(recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len) == -1,
                    "recvfrom() error");
    long filesize = strtol((const char *) packet.data, NULL, 0);
    printf("filesize: %ld\n", filesize);

    while ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len))) {
        abort_on_error(n == -1, "recvfrom() data error");
        // packet.data[n] = '\0';
        // printf("%s\n", packet.data);
        if (!(strcmp((const char *) packet.data, END_FLAG))) {
            break;
        }

        int num_packet = filesize / n;
        // printf("num_packet: %d\n", num_packet);

        count += n;
        if(!num_packet){
            fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), n-(n-filesize), file);
            printf("byte to write: %ld\n", n-(n-filesize));
        }
        else {
            if(count <= filesize) {
                fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), n-8, file);
                printf("byte to write: %d\n", n);
            }
            else if ((count > filesize) && (filesize-num_packet*n-8) && !status) {
                    fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), filesize-num_packet*(n-8), file);
                    printf("byte to write: %ld\n", filesize-num_packet*(n-8));
                    status = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Tot Bytes received: %d\n", count);
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    run(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    return 0;
}
```

For files less than 1400 bytes it works perfectly!
If the file is larger than 1400 bytes (more packet for sent it) then some junk bytes are added.
I can't find why!

Comment: Now everything works fine, I made some mistakes with indexes in the server loop for writing the file. Still having a bytes loss for large file, but this is due to the size of the socket buffers, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now everything works fine. I messed with ifs in while loop in **server.c**.

The **run()** function in **server.c**:

```
void run(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *cliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
int n = 0, count = 0, w = 0;
long received = 0, writed = 0;
socklen_t len;
// char buf[MAXLINE];
FILE *file;
PACK packet;

len = clilen;
n = recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len);
abort_on_error(n == -1, "recvfrom() filename error");
// buf[n] = 0;
printf("Received from client: [%s]\n", packet.data);

file = fopen((const char *) packet.data, "w+");
abort_on_error(file == NULL, "fopen() error");

// abort_on_error(setvbuf(file, buf, _IOFBF, MAXLINE*MUL), "setvbuf() error");

packet.seq_num = 0;
packet.status = 0;
memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
memcpy(packet.data, "ok", strlen("ok"));
abort_on_error(sendto(sockfd, (struct pkt *) &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, len) == -1,
                "sendto() ok error");

memset(packet.data, 0, sizeof(packet.data));
abort_on_error(recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len) == -1,
                "recvfrom() error");
long filesize = strtol((const char *) packet.data, NULL, 0);
printf("filesize: %ld\n", filesize);

int num_packet = filesize / sizeof(packet.data);
int packet_header_size = sizeof(packet) - sizeof(packet.data);
int last_size = filesize-num_packet*(n-packet_header_size);

while ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, cliaddr, &len))) {
    abort_on_error(n == -1, "recvfrom() data error");

    if (!(strcmp((const char *) packet.data, END_FLAG))) {
        printf("END_FLAG received. Stopping receiving data.\n");
        break;
    }

    received += n;
    count += 1;
    // memset(buf, (int) packet.data, sizeof(packet.data));
    printf("Bytes received: %d\n", n);

    // printf("num_packet: %d\n", num_packet);

    if (!num_packet) {
        printf("byte to write: %ld\n", filesize);
        w = fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), filesize, file);
        printf("byte writed: %d\n", w);
        writed += w;
    }
    else {
        if (count <= num_packet) {
            printf("byte to write: %d\n", n-packet_header_size);
            w = fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), n-packet_header_size, file);
            printf("byte writed: %d\n", w);
            writed += w;
        }
        else {
            printf("byte to write: %d\n", last_size);
            w = fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(char), last_size, file);
            printf("byte writed: %d\n", w);
            writed += w;
        }
    }
}
printf("Tot Bytes writed: %ld\n", writed);
printf("Tot Bytes received: %ld\n", received);
fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

junk bytes at the end of string a dead giveaway for a missing string nul termination problem.

here:

```
memcpy(packet.data, target, strlen(target));
```

or here:

```
memcpy(packet.data, "ok", strlen("ok"));
```

you're copying the string without the terminator.

now on reception you have no way of knowing where the string ends and neither does `fprintf`.

So just use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` when copying strings. It'll work and add the nul termination char

```
strcpy(packet.data, target);
```

and

```
strcpy(packet.data, "ok");
```

Comment: When I send target or "ok" string it works fine! the problem is in the loop that send the file. Only the file is afflicted by the junk bytes at position of 1400 byte. but thanks